# GVim flickers where it would normally sound a bell

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim

When I try to (for example) scroll down past the "end" of the file, using pageDown or the down arrow key, GVim would traditionally make a sound. I have disabled this, but another annoying thing it does, is it flickers (presumably to "alert" the user). How can I turn this off?

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 with the Gnome-3 PPA installed. I have a "ATI Technologies Inc M880G [Mobility Radeon HD 4200]" graphics card.

Cheers,
John H.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> GVim would traditionally make a sound. I have disabled this, *[...]*

You've discovered what `:help visualbell` tells you.  The `visualbell` setting does *not* disable the bell.  It *changes* the bell so that instead of outputting the `bel` terminfo sequence (termcap code `bl`) it outputs the `flash` terminfo sequence (termcap code `vb`).

To *disable* the bell you must actually null out one of those terminfo sequences, since vim has no way to specify that you don't actually want a "bell" of either sort at all, but only has a way to change between two types of bell.

You can override a terminal's capabilities from within vim with the `:set` command.  The settable variables in vim that override terminal capabilities are named after the termcap names, not the terminfo names, and vim doesn't have a `t_bl` variable.  So you have to null out the `flash` capability, with the variable named after its termcap code `vb`, since one cannot null out the `bel` capability, and *also* select that as the bell that you are using.

```
:set visualbell t_vb=
```

Comment: This works, but no when I put it in my vimrc? How do I make it work from my vimrc?

Comment: Again, `:help visualbell` would have told you the answer to this one.  You use `.gvimrc`.

Comment: I've been trying to avoid .gvimrc on purpose. I found the answer by adapting yours and merging with something I found on the internet. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so thanks to JdeBP for his answer which worked great when inserted into GVIM during runtime, but not when put into the .vimrc. I found the way round [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/disable-visual-bell-in-insert-mode-for-PHP-file-td1157088.html). The answer is to put this in your .vimrc:

```
" - Stop the bell ringing all the time when you do something dumb
" - or unnecessary.
set visualbell t_vb=
au GuiEnter * set visualbell t_vb=
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the vim "visual bell" feature enabled, which alerts the user with a flash each time the bell would traditionally sound (as you suspected).

You can disable it for the current session by typing:

```
:set novb
```

or more permanently disable it by adding the line `set novb` in your `.vimrc`.